# environment with local \newunicodechar{ä}{ae} or similar -- is it possible?

Tags: xetex, unicode, characters, mapping

I'm using xelatex with utf8-input. I'm trying to write a LaTeX environment inside of which every source code `ä` is printed as ae, every `ö` as oe etc. I found a number of ways that don't work, but so far none that does. I put the error messages under the respective lines of code:

```
<!-- language: lang-latex -->
\documentclass{minimal}
\XeTeXinputencoding{utf8}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{noumlauts}{%
% Neither of these works:
%   \newunicodechar{ä}{ae}
      %   ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
%
%   \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E4}{ae}
      %   ! Undefined control sequence. (\DeclareUnicodeCharacter)
%
%   \catcode`ä=\active\def ä{ae}%
      %  ! Missing control sequence inserted.
      %  <inserted text> 
      %                  \inaccessible
%
%   \makeatletter\@namedef{u8:\detokenize{ä}}{ae}\makeatother 
      %     ! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
      %     \@ ->\spacefactor 
      %                      \@m {}
}{}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
   \begin{noumlauts}
      \noindent Bräsige Mägen\\
      \emph{should look exactly like}\\
      Braesige Maegen
   \end{noumlauts}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define a conditional and redefine `ä` to do something when the condition is true and something else when the condition is false.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newif\ifnoumlauts
\newenvironment{noumlauts}
  {\noumlautstrue}
  {}
\newunicodechar{ä}{\ifnoumlauts ae\else ä\fi}


\begin{document}
\noindent Bräsige Mägen (with umlauts)

\bigskip

\begin{noumlauts}
\noindent Bräsige Mägen\\
\emph{should look exactly like}\\
Braesige Maegen
\end{noumlauts}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\XeTeXinputencoding` should not be used. Also, don't load `xltxtra` unless you really need its features (probably not), but rather `fontspec`.

You can ease defining the characters by an abstraction:

```
\newcommand{\defnoumlauts}[2]{%
  \newunicodechar{#1}{\ifnoumlauts #2\else #1\fi}
}
\defnoumlauts{ä}{ae}
\defnoumlauts{ö}{oe}
\defnoumlauts{ü}{ue}
```

Comment: Yes, @egreg, (I called the conditional `ifTT`), this way I can skip the environment and just have a group `{\ifTT ä becomes ae}`. And in the same way I can turn en-dashes into single dashes, guillemets into single straight quotes etc. (I'm playing with some reenactments of historic typewriter fonts.)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begingroup 
\gdef\changeumlautcatcodes{%
 \catcode`\ä=13}
\changeumlautcatcodes
\gdef\switchumlauts{% 
 \defä{ae}}
\endgroup  

%------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{noumlauts}{%
\changeumlautcatcodes\switchumlauts}{}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
   \begin{noumlauts}
      \noindent Bräsige Mägen\\
      \emph{should look exactly like}\\
      Braesige Maegen
   \end{noumlauts}

Bräsige   
\end{document}
```